# Что за горизонтальный скрол при использовании bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap, только сетку. Пол макета сверстал, только заметил горизонтальный скрол замером точь в точь как вертикальная полоса прокрутки.Скажите как его убрать и откуда он?

Comment: Поизучайте css, конкретно свойство overflow.. Поинспектируйте ваш код в браузере, попереключайте примененные стили .. Поверстайте пока без бутстрапа..

Comment: Я верстал без бутстрапа, и такого не наблюдал.
overflow проходил на float элементах, имею представление.
В инспекторе особо ничего не увидел.
Может Вы все таки выдавите из себя хотя бы почему так происходит и вина ли это бутстрапа или нет.Буду признателен.Спасибо.

Comment: @KleinenberG По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не поможет, поскольку скорее всего, ошибка в разметке. Например, блок `.container` был размещен в `.container`. Без кода установить причину невозможно, а предложенное автором решение - это заметание пыли под ковер.

Comment: @VenZell, если это заметание пыли, то помогите капнуть глубже, подскажите от куда такое поведение, предложите решение.
Критикуете, предлагайте.

Comment: @KleinenberG, чтобы критиковать, надо видеть ваш код. А вы его не привели в вопросе.

Comment: @VenZell, прошу, https://github.com/KleinenberG/aerostat

Comment: @KleinenberG, блок `<div class="time_fly">`. Внутри блок с таким же классом. Скорее всего, там должен быть `div` с классом `.container`, а не второй `div` с классом `.time_fly`. А сейчас получается, что вы используете `.row` без обертки `.container` и из-за отрицательного `margin` у `.row` у вас появляется горизонтальная прокрутка. Исправьте это - она пропадет. Илья Иджян был прав. Его ответ следует принять, а не ваш.

Comment: @KleinenberG, чтобы обнаружить такие ошибки в будущем, добавляйте стиль (например в редакторе стилей браузера) `* { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); }`. После этого прокручивайте страницу в крайнее правое положение и ищете серую полоску - так вы определите, какой блок вылезает за рамки. Вот картинка: http://i.stack.imgur.com/232dY.png . А еще из-за фиксированной ширины `.how_fly:before` у вас на мобильных устройствах (и ноутбуках) тоже будет горизонтальная прокрутка.

Comment: VenZell, спасибо, Вы правы, это из за использования .row без .container 
Про background тоже возьму на заметку.
Про фикс ширину, это у меня псевдоэлемент, но если я сделаю его 100% он склеится и будет на весь экран и как бы из двух таких состоять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько помню бутстрап - у него `container` имеет `padding`, а `row` - отрицательный `margin`, который тот `padding` компенсирует. Если использовать `row` без контейнера, то блок разъезжается на **30px**. Возможно дело было в этом.

Answer (score -3):

`body{overflow-x:hidden}` - исправило ситуацию